# Scala/Apache Spark Converting DataFrame column values and type, multiple when otherwise

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a primary SQL table that I am reading into Spark and modifying to write to CassandraDB. Currently I have a working implementation for converting a gender from 0, 1, 2, 3 (integers) to "Male", "Female", "Trans", etc (Strings). Though the below method does work, it seems very inefficient to make a seperate Array with those mappings into a DataFrame, join it into the main table/DataFrame, then remove, rename, etc.

I have seen:

```
.withColumn("gender", when(col("gender) === 1, "male").otherwise("female")
```

that would allow me to continue method chaining on the primary table but have not been able to get it working with more than 2 options. Is there a way to do this? I have around 10 different columns on this table that each need their own custom conversion created. Since this code will be processing TBs of data, is there a less repetitive and more efficient way to accomplish this.  Thanks for any help in advance!

```
case class Gender(tmpid: Int, tmpgender: String)

private def createGenderDf(spark:SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  import spark.implicits._
  Seq(
    Gender(1, "Male"),
    Gender(2, "Female"),
    Gender(777, "Prefer not to answer")
  ).toDF
}


private def createPersonsDf(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  val genderDf = createGenderDf(spark)
  genderDf.show()

  val personsDf: DataFrame = spark.read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .load(dataPath + "people.csv")
    .withColumnRenamed("ID", "id")
    .withColumnRenamed("name_first", "firstname")

  val personsDf1: DataFrame = personsDf
    .join(genderDf, personsDf("gender") === genderDf("tmpid"), "leftouter")

  val personsDf2: DataFrame = personsDf1
    .drop("gender")
    .drop("tmpid")
    .withColumnRenamed("tmpgender", "gender")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `when` function which would eliminate your need of creating `genderDf`, `join`, `drop`, `rename` etc. As for your example you can do the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
personsDf.withColumn("gender", when(col("gender") === 1, "male").otherwise(when(col("gender") ===2, "female").otherwise("Prefer not to answer")).cast(StringType))
```

You can add more `when` function in the above nested structure and you can repeate the same for other 10 columns as well.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the gender column that already exists (it is defined as Int type) with some kind of column type conversion or will I have to create a new column with type String and then conditionally set values into that column based on the gender column? I guess this second option would also require a column delete and then a column rename too...

Comment: withColumn will create a new column if gender column doesn't exist and it will replace the values in the column if gender column already exists. To change the datatype of a column in withColumn api, you can use cast. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for the help! Excellent answer that explained exactly what I needed